# Get space details without drive names

Tags: filesystems

if there a way to get drives space details without drive names. E.g., the output of

```
df -h

Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3              20G   15G  4.2G  78% /
/dev/sda6              68G   39G   26G  61% /u01
/dev/sda2              30G  5.8G   22G  21% /opt
/dev/sda1              99M   19M   76M  20% /boot
tmpfs                  48G  8.2G   39G  18% /dev/shm
/dev/mapper/vg3-KPGBKUP4
                   10T  7.6T  2.5T  76% /KPGBKUP4
```

I want the output as below:

```
20G   15G  4.2G  78% 
68G   39G   26G  61% 
30G  5.8G   22G  21% 
99M   19M   76M  20% 
48G  8.2G   39G  18% 
10T  7.6T  2.5T  76%
```

Why I want this? I have several servers and have to make report everyday. This will reduce my work to one tenth. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming filesystems and mount points don't contain blank characters, try:

```
df -hP | awk 'NR>1 { $1=$6="" ; print }' | column -t
```

`df -hP` lists the filesystem statistics without linebreaks for long filesystem names.

`awk 'NR>1 { ... }'` restricts the given action to 2nd and following lines to skip `df`'s header line...

The `awk`-action `{ $1=$6="" ; print }` zeroes the unwanted fields and prints the rest.

Using `{ print $2,$3,$4,$5 }` would do the same job.

`column -t` arranges the whole output as clean table.

---

```
$ cat x
#!/bin/sh
echo '<testing inside a script>'
df -hP | awk 'NR>1 { $1=$6="" ; print }' | column -t
echo '</testing inside a script>'
$ chmod +x x
$ ./x
<testing inside a script>
71G    39G   29G    58%
1006M  0     1006M  0%
10M    208K  9,8M   3%
1006M  0     1006M  0%
</testing inside a script>
$ _
```

(I'll remove this again when the problem mentioned in the comments has been solved...)

Comment: You can (and should) use `df -P` to suppress line-breaks.

Comment: Yes... I remember to have known this when my brain was young... *cough!*  *cough!*  :-D   Thanks^n!

Comment: Your concern was right, last line is not as I wanted. My last line is creating problem. it is giving me "7.8T 2.3T 78% /CGFBKUP1" instead of "10T  7.8T  2.3T  78%". That is my main problem, otherwise I could have used "df -h | awk {'print $2, $3, $4, $5'}"

Comment: Excellent. My question was quite out of the box, but you have improvised well. But I am not very good with awk, can you explain in short what you have done here?

Comment: While your command is working perfectly on command line, it is not working on script. It is declaring error near ';'.

Comment: Did you forget the empty string in `$1=$6=""`? Before your edit, your comment had `$1=$6=` without `""`...

Comment: No No I didn't forget anything, as I said command working fine on command line. But when I as using it in script as "df -hP | awk 'NR>1 { $1=$6="" ; print }' | column -t", I think it is taking the double quote after = as closing quote. :(

Comment: `"df -hP | awk 'NR>1 { $1=$6="" ; print }' | column -t"` is in `"..."` in your script? Or which quotes do you expect `=""` to close?

Answer (score 5):

As of GNU coreutils 8.21 ([changelog](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob_plain;f=NEWS;hb=HEAD)), `df` has a `--output` option. Using `sed` to trim the header:

```
df -h --output=size,used,avail,pcent | sed 1d
```

Comment: At least the `df` from coreutils 8.12.197-032bb does not have that option, so it must be pretty new. (That's the version Debian Wheezy currently ships.) Looks useful, though.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, yes never realised this. Since version 8.21, I have added this to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
findmnt -Do SIZE,USED,AVAIL,USE%
```

Here's my output:

```
 SIZE   USED AVAIL USE%
11.8G      0 11.8G   0%
11.8G  63.1M 11.7G   1%
11.8G   920K 11.8G   0%
11.8G      0 11.8G   0%
  12G   8.9G  2.7G  74%
11.8G 410.6M 11.4G   3%
   3G 584.4M  2.4G  19%
   3G 584.4M  2.4G  19%
 2.4G     4K  2.4G   0%
   0      0     0    -
```

So if you're not already using *`findmnt`* for your report, you probably should. You can get a lot more specific than that - but in the above case I specify *`-Do`* to *imitate `df` (as the option is described)* and to limit the output columns. To **remove the column headings, just add *`-n`.*** You don't need any string parsing; ***it's atomic to the output.***

But don't take my word for it:

```
man mount
```

> ...
>   For more  robust  and  definable  output  use *`findmnt(8)`,*  especially in your scripts...

Comment: I can found findmnt on my system. Is it needs to be installed separately.

Comment: It shouldnt - what kernel version do you have?

Comment: @Abhishekdotpy On Debian at least, it's provided by the `mount` package which should definitely be installed.

Comment: @Abhishekdotpy `findmnt` is part of `util-linux` (as is `mount`). Note that this is the source package for the mount package in Debian. Other distros might break things down differently (or just use `util-linux` for everything).

Comment: Its util-linux here, but these tools - the new lsblk, blockdev, findmnt - all rolled in around 3.6 or so i think. Still theyve been around long enough for mount's manpage to tell us to use them - instead of it, no less - so maybe you need to update?

Answer (score 1):

Try This command

```
df -Ph | awk '{print $2, $3, $4, $5}'
```

Comment: You can (and should) use `df -P` to suppress line-breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ df -h | awk 'NR==1{next}{for(i=2;i<NF;i++){printf("%s\t",$i)};print""}'
92G     5.2G    82G     6%  
2.9G    4.0K    2.9G    1%  
1.2G    932K    1.2G    1%  
5.0M    0       5.0M    0%  
2.9G    700K    2.9G    1%  
360G    53G     289G    16%
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but my last line is creating problem. it is giving me "7.8T 2.3T 78% /CGFBKUP1" instead of "10T  7.8T  2.3T  78%". That is my main problem, otherwise I could have used "df -h | awk {'print $2, $3, $4, $5'}"